# Download GitHub history (commits, message, branches, contributors, ...)

Tags: git, github, github-api

Is there a way to download the GitHub history of either the own account or from an organization, where I am a contributor?

I found this page on how to view the commit history, which was quite pleasant but I could not download the information for instance in a json structure: [Link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)

Thus, I want to download the following information in a structured way:

- Repository Name
- Branch information
- Date of Commit / Merge on a specific branch
- Contributor Name / # of contributors
- Commit message

Comment: The specific things you've asked for in the question are in the git data, just clone the repo. The things you wouldn't get that way are issues, review comments, wiki content - the extra stuff GitHub adds *around* git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Clone the repository

The easiest version is to just [clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) the repository without checking out a branch:

```
git clone --bare <url>
```

This downloads the repository with all commits and their responding information including dates and contributors.

You can then access all the information you want using git commands (like shown in [Git Pro as you mentioned](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) or a git wrapper (like libgit2).

## Use the GitHub API

Another possibility is to use the [GitHub API for querying repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos).

You can get repository information using the URL [`https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository).

If you want to get commit information from a repository, use the `commit_url` field of it (usally `https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits`.

With branches, you can use `branch_url` (`https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/branches`).